# How to use Maybe operator to check nullability

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

In the code below, I want to confirm or assert that the returned object or emission from the map operator is not null or if it is null - empty() should be returned.
Please let me know if it is correct or not..

**Activity**

```
companion object {
    fun create(): Maybe<WikiApiService>? {
        return Single.just(
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create()
                )
                .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
                .build()
        )
            .map { retrofit -> retrofit.create(WikiApiService::class.java) }
            .toMaybe()
            //.toObservable()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RxJava will not allow nulls inside the stream, so if `map` returns null, the stream will be terminated with an error event.

What you can do instead is replace `map` with `flatMapMaybe` and return either `Maybe.just(service)` or `Maybe.empty()` if the value is null. Then you can assert whether the result was successful or not in your `subscribe` callback, where `onSuccess` means the value was not null and `onComplete` means the value was null.

Two additional notes. The maybe your are returning should not have to be declared nullable, since that information will be captured inside the Maybe itself. However I'm not sure you need to be handling this null case anyway since as far as I can tell, `retrofit.create` shouldn't be returning null in the first place.

Comment: 1-why specifically use chose .flatMapMaybe() instead of .map(), could not we simply just use .flatMap() instead of .flatMapMaybe()?

Comment: `flatMapMaybe` is more convenient here since it returns a Maybe, whereas `flatMap` returns a Single. For your case however, you could avoid using any map altogether by creating your service inside a `Maybe.fromCallable` block, which will automatically handle nulls for you. [Documentation here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to go with a Optional wrapper like [Guava implementation](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)

or implement it a simple way like:

```
class Optional<T>(private val value: T? = null) {

    fun getValue(): T {
        if (value != null) {
            return value
        } else {
            throw ValueUnavailableException(this.logTag())
        }
    }

    private inline fun <reified T> T.logTag() = T::class.java.simpleName

    fun toNullable(): T? = this.value

    fun hasValue(): Boolean {
        return value != null
    }
    class ValueUnavailableException(className: String = "") : Exception("The optional value for $className is null")
}
```

In your stream usage, use

```
.filter { optionalObject.hasValue() }
```